# Animación de carga pagina VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo una pagina que en la instancia mounted() realiza varias consultas a una api rest y procesa ciertos datos que luego muestra unas graficas, el proceso dura aproximadamente 40 segundos pero en ese momento pues la pagina queda estatica mientras se hacen las operaciones, estoy intentando mostrar una animación de carga mientras acaban las operaciones, pero estas son asincronas, entonces la funcion mounted() se ejecuta completa asi no hayan terminado las funciones que son llamadas en su interior.

```
mounted(){
  this.funcion1();
  this.funcion2();
}
```

Como podria implementar la pantalla de carga cuando todas las tareas de mounted hayan finalizado?

Comment: que hacen funcion1 y funcion2? si tenes consultas a una api, porque no tenes los metodos asincronicos?

Comment: funcion1 y funcion2 son los metodos asincronos que realizan las llamadas a la api

Comment: ok.. y probaste hacer las llamadas asincronicas? las estas haciendo?

Comment: Las estoy haciendo, dentro de los metodos funcion1 y funcion2 hay instrucciones con await en el momento que se llama a la api

Comment: y entonces porque funcion1 y funcion2 no son asincronicas tambien?

Comment: Muchas gracias, al ser funciones asincronas solo basto con hacer async el metodo mounted() y poner await en cada funcion interna.

Comment: era justamente lo que te preguntaba ;)